# Mongoose query with array parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of user ids

Is it possible to query my database using the array as a parameter, returning all the user objects in the database that have the ids in my array?

This was  my previous attempt

```
var array = ['123', '1234', '12345'];

            var query = PUser.find({'userID': array});
                                 query.exec(function(err, users_result) {
                                   if (!err) {
    console.log('all user objects with the array's IDs', users_result);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$in` operator would do the trick.

```
var query = PUser.find({'userID': {$in:array}});
```